# SVG font rendering blurry in header but fine in body

Tags: css, wordpress, svg

I have a strange issue with an SVG font - it is rendering wrong in the header (too thick) but it is fine lower down the page (compare the mobile home in the yellow band with the mobile home in the header ).  I've tried setting antialiasing and setting the stroke to none but nothing seems to help.
Can anyone spot what is happening to this:  Removed

Thank you for you help!

Comment: At the top, it looks like the font has a font-weight of 600, and at bottom is appears to have a font-weight of 500. I _think_ that's the issue.

Comment: Yes, Max is right.  If you set `font-weight: 500` on the header icons, your header icons match the other ones.

Comment: Perfect @MaxStarkenburg & Paul - that was exactly the problem - thanks a million for that :-)!